# VBA runtime error: could not find file

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

Good day all. I have a problem that I simply cannot seem to solve. I am working on an excel program that retrieve data from and update an MS Access 2010 db. I am connecting with the db using ADODB.Connection  and the file (access.accdb) resides in a file server. When the application first launches it uses form1 to get logon details from the user and checks if the user id exists within the db. This function resides within a module and works fine. When I attempt to open the same file from a sub within another user form (form2) I keep getting an error that the file could not be found. I am using the exact same path string as what is used within the module only that this time it is used from within a user form. Below is the code within Module2:

```
Dim con As Object
Dim rs As Object
Dim path As String
path = "path.accdb"
Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
with con
.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
.ConnectionString = "Data Source = " & path & "; Jet OLEDB:Database Password = pwd"
.Open
```

This works fine.
I use the same only from a user form and without the recordset object. I am not retrieving data from the form but rather updating the db. The form is used for data capturing only.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

This is the code that I am using within form1:

```
Dim conn As Object
Dim strPath As String
strPath = "path.accdb" 'same as the path I used from within Module2
Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
with conn
.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
.ConnectionString = "Data Source = " & strPath & "; Jet OLEDB:Database Password = pwd"
.Open    'this is where I get the error.
'Rest of code
```

Error message:
Run-time-error '-2147467259 (80004005)':
Could not find file 'path.accdb'

I have checked the path and it is correct. I have checked for missing references. I must also mention that the database file is located on a folder on my company folder to which I do have access.

Comment: Please add the full code *that doesn't work* to your question. If there are confidential table/field names, change them, but make sure the problem remains (add a dummy `myTable` to your database). See [mcve]

Comment: You probably need the full path/filename rather than just your "path" which actually is the filename only.

Answer (score 0):

Simple syntax problem:

You declare `strPath`:

```
Dim strPath As String
strPath = "path.accdb" 'same as the path I used from within Module2
```

But then you call `Path` instead:

```
.ConnectionString = "Data Source = " & path & "; Jet OLEDB:Database Password = pwd"
```

It happens to all of us when we switch around the spelling of variables :)

** *EDIT* **

Ok... Let's try something different...

Why don't you open your database only once into a global variable?

Maybe opening it a second time in a subform is somehow clashing with your initial connection to the database.

Especially since you don't show us code where you close your connection.

A lot of clues are in your real code that you are not showing us.  If making a global variable doesn't work, you may need to show us your real code with only sensitive info changed.

Comment: Thanks for your response, unfortunately that is not the issue. While the variable name in my post does differ (will correct it now) it is not the issue in my actual code☺

Comment: @user3452354: which is exactly the problem with the truncated / edited code you posted. The problem is not reproducible from that snippet. Again: read [mcve] with special regard to **Complete** and **Verifiable**.